# My question is about WPF button controls rendering on click of check box in UI

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

We have an existing application source code which is developed using WPF and WCF. It's working fine for every user except for one particular user.

There is a functionality in application like on click of check box the button should be enabled on UI. only this specific functionality is not working for the specific user.

Please help me if anybody have an idea regarding WPF controls behaviour or something

We verified about the roles he has to access the application and everything looks good as others but still there is an issue.

Actually on click of checkbox the button should be enabled for the user to access it.

Comment: Did you check the version of each assembly published with the application?

Comment: Can you show some source code how to update/enable the button?

Comment: No code, only the vaguest description of your app. I think there's a high probability your question will be voted to close pretty soon. By "on click of checkbox" do you mean when the checkbox is checked?  Can't you just bind IsEnabled of the button to IsChecked of the checkbox and that'd work for any user? What's role got to do with it?  The fact that it doesn't work and that is just for one user makes me think there's something more complicated going on in your app that you've not explained.